# How to get access to formControl element in formBuilder Array?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to get value from mat-autocomplete but if I'm using formControlName mat-autocomplete doesn't work.

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>...</mat-label>
          <input type="text" matInput aria-label="..."
                     //[formControl]="attributeListCtrl"
                       formControlName="attributeKey"
                       [matAutocomplete]="auto" [readonly]="VOForm.get('VORows').value[i].isEditable">
           <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="onDBAttrSelected()">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let option of attributeList" [value]="option">
               {{option.nameAttribute}}
           </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have seen that some people recommend to use something like `[formControl]= form.get('attributeKey')` but it's not working for me because there's nested array with groups in my formBuilder

```
this.VOForm = this.fb.group({
        VORows: this.fb.array(this.attributeList.map((val:any) => this.fb.group({
            idx: new FormControl('1'),
            attributeKey: new FormControl<string | Attribute>(''),
            attributeValue: new FormControl(val.attribute.allValue),
            action: new FormControl('existingRecord'),
            isEditable: new FormControl(true),
            isNewRow: new FormControl(false),
          })

      )) //end of fb array
      });
```

Comment: you has a FormArray of FormGroups, did you forget the formArrayName or the formGroupName?

Comment: I mean im trying to get access to array element. I think theres should be something like [formControl]="VOForm.get('VORows.attributeKey')" but it doesnt work

Comment: the formControl belong to the formArray, you need know the index of the formArray. You can get it using "dot notation":`[formControl]="VOForm.get('VORows.'+index+'.attributeKey')"`, but to mannage a FormArray we use formArrayName and FormGroupName, see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73617272/how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-a-dropdown-box-in-a-formarray/73617467#73617467) -not related with your question-

Comment: Yes i understand that i should use index but im actually dont know where should i put it

Comment: ```
[formControl]="VOForm.get('VORows.'+i+'.attributeKey')"
 ```
 is working but theres error which says 'AbstractControl<ɵGetProperty ...  is not assignable to type FormControl' value from field successfully getting into form but mat-autocomplete not working with that

Comment: I write an answer, I hope can help you

Answer (score 0):

A FormArray of formGroups is always the same:

You use a getter in .ts

```
get VORows()
{
   return this.VOForm.get('VORows') as FormArray
}
```

In .html

```
<!--declare the form-->
<form [formGroup]="VOForm">

  <!--use formArrayName-->
  <div formArrayName="VORows">

   <!--iterate over the formArray.controls using the "getter"-->
   <div *ngFor="let group of VORows.controls;let i=index"
        [formGroupName]="i">

        <!--here you add the "inputs" using formControlName-->
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>...</mat-label>
          <input type="text" matInput aria-label="..."

                       formControlName="attributeKey"
                       [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
                       ...

             <!--if we want to get reference of another formControl we can use
                 dot notation
             -->                       
            [readonly]="VOForm.get('VORows.'+i+'.isEditable').value">

            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" 
               [displayWith]="displayFn" ...>

               <mat-option *ngFor="let option of attributeList" [value]="option">
                 {{option.nameAttribute}}
             </mat-option>
           </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```