# trying to understand how to use FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript

if I do:

```
this.formArray = new FormArray([
  new FormControl(''),
  new FormControl(''),
]);

formControlA() {
  return this.formArray.at(0);
}

formControlB() {
  return this.formArray.at(1);
}
```

and then have a template use that:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="formControlA>...</mat-select>
<mat-select [formControl]="formControlB>...</mat-select>
```

I get:

> Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange

I don't understand--- why does `.at()` on FormArray return an `AbstractControl` instead of `FormControl`, the type that it was actually instantiated with?

I thought *casting* is bad?  I don't understand how I am supposed to do this sort of thing without doing *bad* casting?

```
formControlA() {
  return this.formArray.at(0) as unknown as FormControl;
}
```

Comment: you can use simply:`return this.formArray.at(0) as FormControl;`. In general a FormArray is mannage in .html using formControlName. but be carefully. A FormArray can be a FormArray of FormsControls or a FormArray of FormGroups, and the .html are different,see among severals, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73617272/how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-a-dropdown-box-in-a-formarray/73617467#73617467)

Answer (score 0):

An `AbstractControl` has at least 3 built-in subclasses :

- `FormControl`
- `FormArray`
- `FormGroup`

And there are some use cases where `this.formArray.at(0)` could legitimately return a `FormGroup` or `FormArray` (e.g. if you nest some forms).

As you have no guarantee that `this.formArray.at(0)` is a `FormControl`, the cast is necessary.

One exception : if you know in advance the number of `FormControl` (but I don't see why you would need a `FormArray` in that case), you could still instantiate the `FormControl` variables separately :

```
formControlA = new FormControl();
formControlB = new FormControl();
formArray = new FormControl([formControlA, formControlB])
```

Comment: but because it's been instantiated WITH a FormControl it should know at(0) is a FormControl!  I do know the number of controls I need, but I am doing this in the context of subclassing and having the base class do:  `createFormControl() { return new FormControl(''); }` and the subclass do: `override createFormControl() { return new FormControl(['', '']); }` then I get `Type '() => FormControl<FormControl<any>[]>' is not assignable to type '() => FormControl<string>'.`  Ughhh.. Typescript is SOOO TERRIBLE.